# Time Evolution of Wigner Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, wigner-transform, deformation-quantization

The Wigner Function is defined as:
$$W(x,p,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int dy \rho(x+y/2, x-y/2, t)e^{-ipy/\hbar}\tag{1}$$
Where $\rho(x, y, t)=\langle x|\hat{\rho}|y\rangle$.
I am supposed to find the time evolution of the Wigner function for the Harmonic Oscillator starting from the von Neumann evolution equation given by:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\left[H,\rho\right].\tag{2}$$
I am not sure how to start, because the von Neumann evolution equation involves the commutator of the Hamiltonian and the operator of interest. However the Wigner function is a function, how can I evaluate the commutator?

Comment: I found one paper which starts with the von Neumann equation of evolution and then takes the Weyl Transform of the commutator. Could that be a start?

Comment: Do you understand Moyal brackets?

Comment: Yes there is actually an exercise on Moyal brackets previously to this one. I guess the way to solve it is by starting from the von Neumann equation and taking the Weyl Transform. The LHS then is just the time derivative of the wigner function because the transform and derivative commute. The RHS then I guess becomes the Moyal bracket?

Comment: Yes. See [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_bracket).

Comment: There are half a dozen textbooks on the subject, like [this one by us](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf). They all get you there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the von Neumann equation:
$$i\hbar\partial \hat{\rho} / \partial t=[\hat{H}, \hat{\rho}]$$
We now take the Weyl Transform on both sides and noting that the partial derivative commutes with the transform and the commutator gets mapped to the Moyal bracket:
$$i\hbar\partial \tilde{\rho} / \partial t=-2i\tilde{H} sin(\hbar \Lambda/2) \tilde{\rho}$$
where the tilde implies they Weyl transform of the operator and $\Lambda = \frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}$
Where the first partial derivative acts to the left and the second to the right.
Now the Weyl transform of the Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator can be shown to be just $\tilde{H}=p^2/2m+m\omega^2x^2$ Now expanding the sine function in a Taylor Series we get:
$$i\hbar\partial \tilde{\rho}=-2i\left((p^2/2m + m\omega^2 x^2)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)^{2n+1}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\right)^{2n+1}\right)\tilde{\rho}\right)$$
Now we express the first term of the sum seperately and we get:
$$i\hbar\partial \tilde{\rho}=-2i\left((p^2/2m + m\omega^2 x^2)\left(\left(\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)^{2n+1}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\right)^{2n+1}\right)\tilde{\rho}\right)$$

Now applying the first term of the sum we get:
$$i\hbar\partial \tilde{\rho}=-i\hbar\left((p/m\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 2 m\omega^2 x\frac{\partial}{\partial p})\tilde{\rho}+\tilde{H}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac{\hbar}{2}\right)^{2n+1}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\right)^{2n+1}\right)\tilde{\rho}\right)$$

The term on the left and the first two terms on the right outside the sum resemble precisely Lioville's equation.
Since the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian is quadratic in $x$ and $p$ and doesn't have any higher order terms the terms of higher order vanish, leaving us with:

$$\partial \tilde{\rho}+(p/m\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + 2 m\omega^2 x\frac{\partial}{\partial p})\tilde{\rho}=0$$

Comment: If I recall correctly, the series on the right will truncate for the h.o.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero does it really? Do you have any references?

Comment: Yes you might want to have a look at: Hillery, M.O.S.M., O'Connell, R.F., Scully, M.O. and Wigner, E.P., 1984. Distribution functions in physics: fundamentals. Physics reports, 106(3), pp.121-167, in particular Eq.(2.54).    This link: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.985.4443&rep=rep1&type=pdf gives me open access but it might not work for you.  I might not be what you want and unfortunately I'm pressed for time...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thanks I will take a look

Comment: I thought about it again. Intuitively higher order terms I think must vanish, because the Weyl transformed Hamiltonian is quadratic in $x$ and $p$, however the next order involves derivatives of third order, so those should vanish I guess, but I'd have to do an exact calculation.

Comment: There are a lot of details in that paper I referenced.

Comment: How can one actually understand higher orders of this special derivative $\Lambda$?

Comment: The Moyal bracket of two functions $W_A\star W_B-W_B\star W_A$ is the Poisson bracket $\hbar\{W_A,W_B\}_P$+ correction terms  (here, this is an expansion in the semi-classical parameter $\hbar$).   The extra pieces in the $\star$ product will eventually subtract to produce a "non-classical" part to the evolution.

Comment: I think I got it now. I will update the solution tomorrow.

Comment: @eeqesri Could you explain for me (or show me some references) where the commutator originally came from?

Comment: @MrProof Do you mean how the commutator gets mapped to the moyal bracket?

Comment: @eeqesri I was meaning the commutator in general where does it come from Indy Schrodinger equation and in Hatree equation. I’m a mathematician and I’m not familiar with the derivations of these equations.

Comment: @MrProof I am not an expert in QM but pretty much any book on QM should be able to explain it. As far as I know the commutator is something like a Poisson bracket in classical mechanics. The commutator is also important for deriving the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. Hope that helps.